# Паковщик файлов в один файл

Tags: php, archive

Прочитал тут тему "архиватор файлов". Пришла мысль можно ли запаковать в один файл много файлов, закодировав особым алгоритмом. Процент сжатия не важен. То есть сжимать не обязательно. Задача запихнуть много файлов и папок в один файл. Как сделать это с помощью PHP?

Так же нужно разархивировать обратно. Это нужно для установки, скажем самописного CMS.

Comment: Реализация утилит ar или tar на php?

Comment: Не обязательно. Достаточно чтобы все файлы оказались в одном файле. Алгоритм не важен, важен результат. Например,когда отправляешь аттачи по почте, файлы пихаются в один "файл" с разделителями и отправляются. Далее клиентская часть вытаскивает аттач из письма. Что-то в этом роде.

Comment: Запустить ar по system()?

Comment: Чаще всего в хостингах такой возможности нет.

Comment: При отправке письма с аттачами они и так "пихаются в один файл с разделителями", см. RFC-1521. И клиентская часть "вытаскивает файлы из письма". Вы, конечно, можете придумать свой вариант, хоть самопальный, хоть с уже готовыми реализациями tar в PHP (их куча, не найти сложно). Останется только написать свой RFC и дождаться, когда все начнут ему следовать :)

Answer (score 1):

http://www.php.net/manual/ru/book.phar.php ? поддерживает gzip сжатие, работает быстро, эффективно и прозрачно.

Answer (score 0):

Простейший алгоритм, только что родился:

```
заголовок
{
    сигнатура (N байт, для верности)
    длина имени (1 или 2 байта)
    имя файла (с путём, длина_имени байт)
    атрибуты (M байт, зависит от целей)   
    длина файла (4 или ? байт)
}
тело_файла
```

И по такой схеме фигачим файлы в выходной поток один за другим. Опционально в заголовок добавляем CRC32, длину заголовка, медод кодирования/упаковки, ctime/mtime, ... - до тех пор, пока не рождается очередной zip, arj, tar, gzip, bzip, rar etc :-)